# Oracle SQL convert number (that stores a timestamp) to human readable date time on select

Tags: oracle

I have a timestamp stored on a column called `ts` of type `NUMBER(15, 0)`, and I want to print their corresponding human readable datetime in any human readable format, like `'2022-03-15 23:08:24'`.

None of what I have tried works, but the most closed thing is:

```
select 
   to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * ts
from my_table;
```

But this translates `ts` to a human readable date, not a datetime. I'm not able to show the hours, minutes and seconds. I think Oracle SQL has functions to translate timestamps to datetimes in a straightforward way, but it requires the timestamp is stored on a `TIMESTAMP` column, but in my case it's a `NUMBER`.

Comment: Dates include times, down to second precision. If you want to preserve milliseconds then use `to_timestamp`. Either way, change your client NLS settings or use `to_char()` to *display* the date or timestamp in the format you want.

Comment: The problem is that when you sum `+1` to a date it adds one day, and that's why `timestamp` is divided by number of days. I don't know how to get show the right amount of seconds inside the day.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have also tried with `to_date('19700101 010000', 'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') + ...` but no luck either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating a date, which retains the time to second precision, but loses the milliseconds. You're also ignoring the time zone your `ts` is nominally in, which is presumably UTC - as an epoch/Unix time.

Anyway, you can change how the date is displayed by changing your session settings, or with `to_char()`:

```
select 
  to_char(
    date '1970-01-01' + (1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * ts,
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
  )
from my_table;
```

If you want to keep milliseconds, and preserve time zone, use a timestamp and intervals instead:

```
select
  to_char(
    timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + ((ts / 1000) * interval '1' second),
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZR'
  ) as string_result
from my_table;
```

With an example `ts` value of 1655977424456, that gives result `2022-06-23 09:43:44.456 UTC`

The result is still UTC. You can also convert the time to a different time zone if that's useful; for example:

```
select
  to_char(
    (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + ((ts / 1000) * interval '1' second))
      at time zone 'Europe/Madrid',
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'
  )
from my_table;
```

The same example `ts` value of 1655977424456 now gives `2022-06-23 11:43:44.456 EUROPE/MADRID`, or just `2022-06-23 11:43:44.456` if you leave the TZR off the format model or convert to a plain timestamp.

And you should *only* convert to a string to display - not to store or manipulate or pass around the actual timestamp value.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8ee884d1bf8c4318275c0eb030296a9e) with some variations.

Comment: Excelent. My timzone is `GMT + 2` but writting `GMT + 2` instead of `UTC` doesn't work.

Comment: @Peregring-lk - it would be better to specify a time zone region rather than an offset - so daylight savings time is honoured, but it's clearer even if you're in a region that doesn't have DST.

Comment: More specifically, it's CEST, which is the same as CET + 1. `CET` works, `CEST` doesn't.

Comment: Ok it worked with `+ interval '1' hour` at the end.

Comment: It's not a good idea to adjust manually though; can't you use e.g. `'Europe/Madrid'`?

Comment: If I replace `UCT` with `Europe/Madrid` doesn't add the 1 hour of daily saving time.

Comment: @Peregring-lk - no, don't replace UTC in the initial 1970 timestamp literal; convert the final timestamp after you've added `ts`, which is still UTC, to a different time zone. I had an example in the db<>fiddle, but I've added it to the question now as well.

Comment: Inside the initial date, `Europe/Madrid` is recognized, but with the `at time zone` keywords doesn't ("timezone region not found). Anyway, I needed the query for testing purposes not for a final product so I will go with adding the hour manually. Good enough for me.